Webcomic/webtoon about a pink-haired human girl who is the last of her species and is adopted by aliens in space
It start with an alien invasion destroying humanity and making them slaves.
I don't remember how the girl (the protagonist) was adopted and transported to a different planet, but I know she uses pink bandages to cover her intimate parts and eventually leaves her foster parents to travel and later gains power with her hair.
There is also a weird shark/lizard that has fallen in love with her in the latest chapters.
I would greatly appreciate for any information, thank you!

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Any idea what site you found it on?

Maybe Mangadex, it's been ~2years ? I am not too sure but it's definitely a site similar

Is this Galaxy!...?
From the Namu Wiki (auto-translated from Korean):

Human civilization on a small planet called Earth was destroyed by the invasion of the warring empire Dectonius, and a human girl, Lera, rescued by the Galactic Federation, was adopted by the Galactic Federation's battleship captain Lerotella and lived as a resident on the alien planet Molan. In the end, he faced endless adversity and enemies. Now she must find a bright future for herself and her humanity, and defend those dear to her against a cosmic crisis looming.


Hard to find much information about this on English-language websites, but it seems to be a Korean webtoon/manhwa about a pink-haired girl named Layla who was rescued from Earth and raised by nice aliens after the Earth was attacked by evil aliens, and is now the last surviving human.
From what I can gather, there are two versions of this: the original, crudely-drawn version from 2009 and a more polished-looking remake from 2016.
